# WordPress importing Template 'Import Process Interrupted'

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I **import** a **template** for the theme that was activated in my local **WordPess**, this message displayed:

"**Import Process Interrupted
We are facing a temporary issue in importing this template.
Read article to resolve the issue and continue importing template.**"

Comment: Importing templates ? Are you using a plugin or something ? What are you doing exactly ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.